# How to set vertical line position?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, xhtml

I am using below code for separating "number" and "description" columns, now my question is how to place this vertical line position where i exactly want, let me describe clearly below steps.

Total width of size is 580px, two columns share this 580 width, one is "number" which is use only 50px and another one is "description" needs to use 530px

here is the code:

```
<div
style="width:1px;height:200px;background-color:black;float:left;"></div>
```

I will be very appreciate if anyone could modify this script little bit and give proper code, picture example is below.

http://www.image-maps.com/PHP_Map_Image.php

NOTE:

I need below script on DIV tag

```
<table style="width: 580px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#ffd700">
<td width="50"></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#cc3399" width="230">main content cell</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#ffd700">
<td width="50"></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#cc3399" width="230">main content cell</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#ffd700">
<td width="50"></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#cc3399" width="230">main content cell</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand how that code of yours would create two columns. Post all the relevant code please

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code there. That said, I'm still not clear on what this is supposed to do, what's the desired outcome, and what's happening instead?

Comment: I removed my answer as it doesn't make sense anymore now that you have added `table` code while you were talking about `div` before. What you need to do is find some information on how to use CSS. In WP you can access the stylesheet file of the theme you use by going to Appearance->Editor. Scroll to the bottom.

Comment: RST...its a great solution, what I understood is I have put the css code on my wp-style sheet and in the post I need to call those css code? am I right?

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/xUCPL/3/

## HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="number">100</div>
    <div class="description">bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.main {float:left;width:580px;background:red;}
/* width change to 40, bcoz of padding */
.number {width:40px;float:left;padding:5px;} 
/* width change to 519, bcoz of border and padding */
.description{width:519px;float:left;border-left:1px solid #000;padding:5px;}
```

Comment: Thank you, if you could modify this code for dividing 50 and 230 ration.     <h1 style="width: 580px; height: 200px; border: 5px solid #000000; text-align: center; background-color:#996666 ">HELO</h1>

Comment: so, you want 580px width, with a combination of 50 and 230 px, which take only 280px. And you want this within <h2> tag? or you wanna use with table tag. please let us clear.

Comment: Hi Yeyene, I need first coulmn 50px and second column 530px total 580 px column. yes using DIV tag